# Replace text with Jquery avoiding an update button

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to replace "Gastos de envío: " to "Shipping costs" on English page.

And I have this code on jquery (it's working) but only the first time that you enter to the page because if you update the shipping costs, the jquery doesn't replace the text.

How can I replace text avoiding the update button?:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

  jQuery('label[for^="shipping_method_0').contents().filter(function() { 
    return this.nodeType === 3 && jQuery.trim(this.textContent).length;
  })
  .replaceWith('Shipping\ costs: ');

});
```

[image: code in html]
[image: frontend website]

**Update**: I am not allowed to change the html

Comment: when shipping costs are updating?

Comment: When you click on button, it's not refreshing the page only update that part of the code, I suppose that is javascript

Comment: Why is this necessary in the first place? Why do you have non-English text like that, occurring in the English version of your site?

Comment: $('#id').text('your text');

Answer (score 0):

You can use like This Hope it's Help You

```
<label>
    Gastos de envío
    <span class="woocommerce-Price....">120.87 €</span>
    <small>(incl. VAT)</small>
</label>
<button id="YourBTN">SUBMIT</button>
```

and you want to apply js like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#YourBTN").click(function(){
            $("label").each(function() {
              var text = $(this).text();
              text = text.replace("Gastos de envío", "Shipping costs");
              $(this).text(text);
          });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: mmm But I can't change html >_<

Comment: Okay let me try something else

Comment: Please try with a new script